# Dragging Index Formula down rows and changing the return column

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, row

I have a formula that I am using (after you paste it press "Enter+Ctrl+Shift" to run it as it has an array inside of it):

=INDEX('[Database_IRR 200-2S.xlsm]HE 171'!**$F:$F**,SMALL(IF('Operation base Q'!$H$5='[Database_IRR 200-2S.xlsm]HE 171'!$A:$A,ROW('[Database_IRR 200-2S.xlsm]HE 171'!$A:$A),""),1))

For the next cell below it (next row below), when I drag down the formula, I want the first part of the formula to change from **'[Database_IRR 200-2S.xlsm]HE 171'!$F:$F** to **'[Database_IRR 200-2S.xlsm]HE 171'!$G:$G**

The formula should look like this in the next row below after the above change is made **(the bold is the change I want)**:

=INDEX('[Database_IRR 200-2S.xlsm]HE 171'!**$G:$G**,SMALL(IF('Operation base Q'!$H$5='[Database_IRR 200-2S.xlsm]HE 171'!$A:$A,ROW('[Database_IRR 200-2S.xlsm]HE 171'!$A:$A),""),1))

I have also posted this on: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/dragging-index-formula-down-rows-and-changing-the-return-column.1139235/

Comment: You might be able to replace **`$F:$F`** with **`INDEX($F:$Z,0,ROWS($1:1))`**.  The `0` for the rows argument returns all the rows, and the `Columns` argument should increment the returned column the way you want.  Change the `$Z` to whatever your last column might be.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld could you take a look at my other post regarding a similar situation if you get a chance? Thank you in advance my friend: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62782956/how-to-do-a-vlookup-with-offset-or-small-array